# Predictions into the future Azure Machine Learning Studio Designer

Tags: prediction, forecasting, azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently developing an automated mechanism where I use the Azure Machine Learning Designer (AMLD). During development i used an 80/20 Split to test the efficency of my predictions.
Now i want to go live but I've missed the point where i can actually predict into the future.

I currently get a prediction for the last 20% of my data so i can compare them to the actual data. How do i change it so that the prediction actually starts at the end of my data?

A part of my prediction process is attached:

[image]

Comment: The training and testing sets will be distributed randomly in the ratio we mentioned . So the last 20% of the dataset is not used for testing. 
The prediction will be done by comparing the training set result with the test set data. We can’t start the prediction at the end of the data. The prediction have to be achieved with the data available.

Comment: But there needs to be a way to predict into the future. What would be the reason of a prediction into past data? Maybe append only dates without values that are exactly 20% of the data so that i train the model with the past data and score it into the "new" dates?

Comment: You can create a model using the past data, by training it. Create as a model that can be re-used for specific data format. In future you can reuse the same model. But the procedure in machine learning is constant that, we need to split the existing data and train the model. Check with the future data in the same format. If you really need that code block. I can share as a sample.

Comment: Yes, a sample code would be much appreciated. I don't really get the problem, sorry..
But supervised works by understanding past data with connections between time and value to then use that knowledge to predict values where only the time is given. Can't i or how do i train the model with the past data and then tell the algorithm to predict the values for future dates? Sorry if i am a slow learner

Comment: It's not at all an issue @Marc. I will share the sample in Answer block and simulate the code with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with the comments:

Example problem statement: Predicting salary based on experience.

The dataset consists of three columns and salary is the dependent variable and first two columns will be independent variables

[image]

The sample code starts from below.

```
#importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

#Training the linear regression model on complete dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)
#Training with the model. 
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, y)
```

As a sample I am giving polynomial regression

```
#visualize Linear regression results.
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (Linear Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position Level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

#Visualize Polynomial regression results
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (Polynomial Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

#Predicting new result with linear regression-> this can help you
lin_reg.predict([[6.5]])

#Predicting new result with polynomial regression
lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[6.5]]))
```

Go through the flow of implementation of two different regression models on same dataset and how the difference in results will be.